# Howto do VCSA redundancy?

Tags: vmware-vcenter, redundancy, master-slave

We are currently in the process of setting up a new VMWare environment which is now only in lab phase. We are studying the possibility to have a vCenter cluster with an active and a standby/mirrored/whatever... vCenter, this is with the VCSA alternative.

The idea is that we are likely to do scripting using vCenter webservices so we would like to avoid single point of faillure by having a redundant setup. Basically we want our vCenter to be reachable all the time.

Unfortunately, we can't do linked-mode due to lack of ADAM support and putting SRM with dual vcenter in place seems a bit too much, especially since I want to manage only 1 vCenter. I also looked at the disk replication feature and that would work except that the recovery vm won't auto-boot the vm in case of crash (as far as I know).

So, I'm seaking advices from you experts on what's the easiest way to do a VCSA redundant setup.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a late asnwer but here it is:

I do not believe that there is any failover options for vCSA as it cannot be in linked-mode as a you said (If it is down, there is no other vCenter that would trigger a failover so you would have to do this manually.

I aware that the following does not reply to your question however note that vCenter server isn't critical (It is mainly a management/monitoring solution) and can be restored manually in a timely fashion. The only reason for failover would be for reliability when using VMware View/Cloud and scheduled operations. Hopefully it will come in the future.

The backup options (redundancy) are multiple :

- [Backup vPostGres](http://bidabe.ddns.net/?p=360)
- Replicate vCSA with the vSphere Replication appliance
- Backup vCSA with the Data Protection appliance